# Artifactory storage keeps growing

Tags: mysql, storage, artifactory

Artifactory storage summary says that binary size is 1.95TB, Artifact Size: 3,59TB. But Filestore is 5.1 TB and it keeps only growing.
It seems that there is about 3TB space in use by old artifacts. Is there a way to investigate what is consuming this storage and can it be cleaned up somehow?

Comment: Are you using the trash? You might have all the storage used by the trash can. If so, you can empty it or even configure not to use it at all.

Comment: Thank you for the remark; indeed we use the trash can but it only occupies 0.05% (2GB) of storage (according to the GUI). So I guess that will not help.

Comment: Can you check the file system and see the distribution of the storage? Look under (assuming linux) /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory. See what directory is consuming so much of the storage.

Comment: @Peter  When is the last time your Artifactory ran a garbage collection? it is possible that you have storage consumed by artifacts which are no longer in use and should be cleaned by the GC process

Comment: @Dror: Garbage collection is running every 4 hours every day.

Comment: @Eldad: I had a closer look at the directory sizes. It appears that the database/backup/current/repositories directory is consuming about 3.6TB. We configured daily incremental backup. So it looks as if I have to change the backup somehow. Any good recommendations?

Comment: Backups can eat up a LOT of storage. Company policy is your first priority. Consider putting it on a separated mounted volume. Look at https://jfrog.com/whitepaper/best-practices-for-artifactory-backups-and-disaster-recovery/ for more.